# Error while executing read prompt in csh and converting to multiline alias

Tags: scripts, alias, csh, tcsh

Hey everyone i have this issue where i have a sample program in csh (i know its not the best language to use for scripting but i dont have an option here) its as foll:

```
#!/bin/csh    
echo 'please enter values' 
read a 
read -e b
echo "My values are $a and $b"
```

As you might see my second read is going to take a file input. This is needed as my actual program will have that; now what i want to do is to convert this to alias however when i execute the above script i get the foll. output

```
please enter values
read: Command not found
read: Command not found
a: Undefined variable
```

How can i fix this and also i want to convert this all 4 lines into a multiline alias. I have written single line alias in the past with no issues but not sure about multiline. if someone can help out i'll be really grateful

Comment: What implementation of `csh` are you using? neither BSD `csh` nor the Tenex `tcsh` has a `read` function AFAIK. I notice you don't show a "shebang" at the top of the code - which makes me suspect you are executing it from bash, and it is actually being interpreted by bash.

Comment: i had read it somewhere that if u execute the file ie ./file.csh the read command would work unlike when you just source the file and thats how i was able to use it till now. and as far as the "shebang" i didnt mention it but when i do echo $SHELL i get /bin/tcsh so i am assuming its been interpreted as tcsh and not bash

Comment: Please add an appropriate shebang such as `#!/bin/csh` or `#!/usr/bin/env csh` to your script and update your question with the output of `./file.csh` after that. FWIW `echo $SHELL` will usually tell you what your *login* shell is set to - but that's not necessarily the interactive shell that you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the C shell does not have a built-in `read` function similar to that of Bourne-type shells.

I am **not** proficient in `csh` synatax but as far as I know, the nearest equivalent is to use the special variable `$<` . From `man csh`:

> ```
>        $<      Substitutes a line from the standard input, with no further
>                interpretation.  It can be used to read from the keyboard
>                in a shell script.
> ```

e.g.

```
$ cat myscript.csh
#!/bin/csh

echo 'please enter values'
set a = $<
set b = $<
echo "My values are $a and $b"
```

which gives

```
$ ./myscript.csh
please enter values
123
abc
My values are 123 and abc
```

Note that there are implementation-dependent differences in how assignments from `$<` handles multi-word input - in particular, the Tenex `tcsh` does not quote input by default, instead requiring `$<:q` to get the same behavior as BSD `csh`. Also there is (as far as I know) no built-in readline editing support equivalent to the bash shell's `read -e`.

As far as multi-line aliases are concerned, they do seem to work:

```
% alias jo '\
echo "please enter values "\
set a = $< \
set b = $< \
echo "My values are $a and $b"'
%
% alias
jo
echo "please enter values "
set a = $<
set b = $<
echo "My values are $a and $b"
```

Testing it

```
% jo
% please enter values
123
foo bar
My values are 123 and foo bar
%
```

however it's not a feature that I would recommend relying on.

Comment: wow thats a lot to take....but thanks a lot for that....